# Dockerfile supervisord cannot find path

Tags: docker, supervisord

For some reason supervisord cannot start up when executing docker run... If I log out the path where the configuration is stored for supervisord I can clearly see that the file is present.

Below is the part of my Dockerfile thats not currently commented out.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Kevin Gilbert

# Update Packages
RUN apt-get -y update

# Install basics
RUN apt-get -y install curl wget make gcc build-essential

# Setup Supervisor
RUN apt-get -y install supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

Here is the error I get in terminal after running.

```
remote-testing:analytics-portal kgilbert$ docker run kmgilbert/portal
Error: could not find config file  /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with the exec form of **[`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd)**:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

or with the shell form

```
CMD /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
```

Depending on the OS used by the base image, you might not even have to specify the `supervisord.conf` in the command line ([see this example](http://tiborsimko.org/docker-running-multiple-processes.html), or [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/#/building-our-image))

Comment: I hit a strange issue here.... on windows docker, `CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord -c /myconf/supervisord.conf"] worked, but failed on ubuntu when building, now with quotes around all parts the command works on ubuntu.

Comment: @monkut Strange. Can you ask that as a separate question?

Comment: Really looks like a docker for windows bug... `["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/myconf/supervisord.conf"]` also works on windows, but since `["/usr/bin/supervisord -c /myconf/supervisord.conf"]` worked on windows I was tripped up when trying to use the same dockerfile on ubuntu.

Comment: Hey, Docker image was built successfully after removing following above. But while running `docker run imagename`  I am getting following error. `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"supervisord\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled `  . Can you please help me fix this?

Comment: @ascii_walker It is best to ask that as a separate question rather than a comment to a 4 years old answer. That way, you can add details as to your current (2020) Docker setup (Docker version, OS of host, OS of guest, image tag, ...)

Comment: Hey, Sorry I meant to comment this to my own posted question only.  Here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63599851/bin-sh-1-cannot-create-etc-nginx-nginx-conf-directory-nonexistent-the-comma?noredirect=1#comment112466459_63599851

Answer (score 2):

It happended to me on Alpine linux 3.9, but eventually ran successfully with

```
CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "<path_to_conf_file>"]
```