# cannot create /etc/nginx/nginx.conf: Directory nonexistent and starting container caused "exec: \"supervisord\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I am building docker image to deploy flask app with uwsgi/nginx.

Here are relevant file for to create a docker container for same

`Dockerfile` content

```
FROM python:3.6

MAINTAINER Dockerfiles

RUN mkdir /trell-ds-framework
WORKDIR /trell-ds-framework
ADD . /trell-ds-framework/
RUN python setup.py bdist_wheel
# install uwsgi now because it takes a little while
RUN pip3 install uwsgi
# copy over our requirements.txt file
# upgrade pip and install required python packages
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -U pip
RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -c "import nltk;nltk.download('stopwords')"
# setup all the configfiles
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx_app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
COPY supervisor_app.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/


# add (the rest of) our code

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["supervisord"]
```

`supervisor_app.conf` content

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:uwsgi]
command = /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /trell-ds-framework/uwsgi.ini
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:nginx]
command = /usr/sbin/nginx
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

`nginx_app.conf` content

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name ip_address;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///trell-ds-framework/app.sock;
    }
}
```

`uwsgi.ini` file content

```
[uwsgi]
callable = app
chdir = /trell-ds-framework
wsgi-file = /trell-ds-framework/wsgi.py
socket = /trell-ds-framework/app.sock
master = true
processes = 2
chmod-socket = 666
enable-threads = true
```

when I am trying to build the docker image in trell-ds-framework directory (using command  `docker build -t ds_backend .` , I am getting following error on line 13/17 of Dockerfile

```
Step 13/17 : RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 ---> Running in 1ee5628a4bc2
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /etc/nginx/nginx.conf: Directory nonexistent
The command '/bin/sh -c echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I checked this `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file exists in my virtual machine.

I am taking help from this [Tutorial - Deploy flask app with uwsgi/nginx using docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744884/setting-flask-app-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-in-docker-container) which seems to be working. But in my case its giving that error.

After following comments instruction I could build docker image successfully. Now I am getting this error below.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"supervisord\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

Can anybody help me out here. Thanks in advance.

PS: I am very new to these things. Any leads highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you need to add `deamon off;` to the `nginx.conf`. I would add it to `supervisord` configuration, like this `/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"`, instead of just `/usr/sbin/nginx`.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. Had replaced that line with `RUN /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"` as you suggested . Not its giving error `/bin/sh: 1: /usr/sbin/nginx: not found
` . Although `/usr/sbin/nginx` exists in ubuntu

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough. :) You don't need it in the Dockerfile, add the line to the `supervisor_app.conf`, as the `command`.

Comment: `[program:nginx]
command = /usr/sbin/nginx
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
daemon=off`

Okay. Got it . So I have added `daemon = off` in nginx with command=/usr/sbin/nginx;
Docker image is building . Will let you know the status in couple of minute

Comment: Hey, Docker image was built successfully after removing following above. But while running docker run imagename I am getting following error. docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"supervisord\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown. ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled  . Can you please help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since managing answers with comments is nearly impossible, I'll post the outlook of the `supervisor_app.conf` file here:

```
[program:nginx]
command = /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

I think it's what you need.

---

EDIT: I just saw the comment about supervisor not being found. It seems that you haven't installed it in Dockerfile. Here's how to add it:

```
apt-get install -y supervisor
```

You can add just the package name in one of the steps, like this:

```
RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates supervisor
```

Note that you already have that line, just without `supervisor`.

---

EDIT2: As per @thsutton's answer, you also need to add `nginx` package, the same way you did for `supervisor`.

Comment: Hey @Marko E,  Thanks for posting answer here. I tried this new supervisor_app.conf just now. Had already added line for supervisor in Dockerfile.  
`$ docker run ds_backend
UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching ' 
It gives following error now.  Seems its not able to find supervised_app.conf file.

Comment: COPY nginx_app.conf  /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
COPY supervisor_app.conf  /etc/supervisor/conf.d/

Is there any issue with these lines ?  I checked ` /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`  and ` /etc/supervisor/conf.d/`  doesn't exists in my ubuntu on which I am trying to build docker image

Comment: Also I have this CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"] as the last line of docker and configuration file. Anyway posting this new issue in another question

Comment: Here I have posted new question for this new issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63608075/userwarning-supervisord-is-running-as-root-and-it-is-searching-for-its-configur

Answer (score 1):

Does the `python:3.6` image already contain `nginx` and `supervisord`? If not, it is up to you to install them (with `apt-get` or a similar command, as appropriate).

The fact that the nginx config file doesn't exist, and the binary doesn't exist would suggest to me that maybe the packages are *not* installed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer.  Currently that error not coming as you can see from first answer.  I checked ` /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and ` /etc/supervisor/conf.d/` doesn't exists in my ubuntu on which I am trying to build docker image .  Does it mean that this path also don't exists in docker container? How do I check.

Comment: It does not matter whether or not the files exist in your Ubuntu workstation, just inside the container. You can check to see if they are the `python:3.6` image you are using by running a shell in it with `docker run --rm -ti python:3.6 bash` and then using tools like `ls -lashd /etc/nginx`

Comment: Oh Okay. Got it. Thanks a lot. shell command worked but `ls -lashd /etc/nginx` gives error `ls: cannot access '/etc/nginx': No such file or directory`  not running.  Does it means nginx is not installed in the container?

Comment: Sure sounds like it. I would add appropriate `RUN` commands to install whatever packages you want (sounds like you want nginx and supervisord to both be in the container?) to your Dockerfile. I generally find that having all the "install foo" bits at the start and all the "configure bar" bits at the end works out pretty OK.

Comment: Okay. Cool. Will try that. Thanks